# My transactional email is sent many times

Tags: email, script

I have an issue with my shell script. I'm trying to send a transactionnal email to a list of specific customers (more or less 1000 customers) Sometimes, an email is sent 2 or 3 times to the same customer and I don't understand why.

I've got my customers collection and I made a loop on it.

```
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('birthday_mail');

foreach( $customerList as $customer ){

    $emailTemplateVariables = array();
    /*
     ...
    */

    $emailTemplate->send($customer->getEmail(),'John Doe', $emailTemplateVariables);
}
```

This script is execute with Pentaho Data Integration.
I'm wondering if my code is correct and the problem is on Pentaho execution or if I made a mistake in my script.

Answer (score 0):

```
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('birthday_mail');

$sent = array();

foreach( $customerList as $customer ){

    $emailTemplateVariables = array();
    /*
     ...
    */
    if (!in_array($customer->getEmail(), $sent)) {
        $emailTemplate->send(,'John Doe', $emailTemplateVariables);
        $sent[] = $customer->getEmail();

    }

}
```

You may have duplicate entries in the database. So the code above adds the already sent email addresses to an array and then only sends the email of the email address in the loop doesn't exist in the array.